# Double and Single quotes on Insert SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to insert dynamic elements to a table using Javascript and SQLite, I have a problem when one of the values has a single quote AND a double quote, for example  -- 7' inches" vinyl -- I KNOW THAT EXAMPLE MAKES NO SENSE, but the users of this app insert all kind of crap in the forms.

My query would be messed up with the "' everywhere, my question is: is there a function or something that could make me use the real string that I need without breaking everything?

This is the code:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {   
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO articulo (codart) VALUES (" + validate(item.CODART) + ")");
});


function validate(item){
        if(item == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            return "'" + item + "'";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's in the string shouldn't break your query. If it does, that's a security issue. How are you building the query? We can't tell you what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: You need to look at a method of escaping the quote characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could escape single quotes by doubling them, but it would be easier to just use parameters:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO articulo (codart) VALUES (?)", [validate(item.CODART)]);
```

Comment: Plus 1 for parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes should not create a problem. Try replacing the single quotes by two single quotes.

Change the function to:

```
function validate(item){
    if(item == null){
        return null;
    }else{
        return "'" + item.replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }
}
```